# How do I change a variable from a different class in Java?

Tags: java, class, variables

### How do I change a variable from a different class in Java?

I'm trying to change a variable from another class, and use it back in the first class.

I make a variable in class First, and give it a value of 1. Then I try to change the value of the same variable to 2 in class Second, but it changes back to 1 when I use it in class First.

*I'm new to Java and don't know very much yet, so if you could try and keep the answers simple, that would be great :)*

---

**Class First:**

```
public class First {

    public static void main(String args[]){


    int var = 1; //Variable i'm trying to change from class "Second"

    Second Second = new Second();

    System.out.println(var); //Prints out 1

    Second.test(var); 

    System.out.println(var); // Prints out 1 again, even though I changed it

}
}
```

---

**Class Second:**

```
public class Second {

    void test(int var){
    /*
     * 
     * I try to change var to 2, and it works in this class
     * but when it doesn't change in the class "First"
     * 
     */
    var = 2;
    System.out.println(var); //Prints out 2

}
}
```

---

**What the output looks like:**

1 
2 
1

**What i'm trying to get:**

1 
2 
2

---

*Ive tried to find answers to this, but all of the answers that I could find didnt make any sense to me, as im very new to Java and programming.*

Comment: You need to work through some basic tutorials. Have a look at this page about [variable scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html), it explains quite clearly why your code does not do what you expect.

Comment: You can use **class** variables, not **local**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is

```
Second.test(var);
```

It's not a bug. It's just not doing what you think its doing.

A primitive (an `int` is called a primitive...it's not an object) passed to a function may be changed in that function, but *in a copy*. As soon as the function is done, the original value is the same, *because it was never altered to begin with*.

What you want is

```
int test(int var){
   var = 2;
   System.out.println(var); //Prints out 2
   return  var;
}
```

And then instead of

```
Second.test(var);
```

use

```
var = Second.test(var);
```

There is actually no point in the parameter at all. It is equivalent to

```
var = Second.test();

...

int test(){
   int var = 2;
   System.out.println(var); //Prints out 2
   return  var;
}
```

I hope this helps. Good luck, welcome to Java, and welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2):

Java is [pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference/40523#40523), it means that you are passign a copy of `var`. What you can do is to make method `test()` to return a `int`

```
int test(int var){
    ...
    var = 2;
    System.out.println(var); //Prints out 2
    return var;
}
```

and then assign its result (the value the method `test()` returns) to `var`:

```
var = second.test(var);
System.out.println(var); //Prints out 2
```

**Note:**

In

```
Second Second = new Second();
```

you shouldn't use the name of a class as a name of a variable. Do this sintead:

```
Second second = new Second();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `var` parameter in `test` method of class `second` is a copy, not a reference or pointer. So you can not change the value of `var` in class `First`.

To achieve your goal, you could declare `var` as a global variable, like this:

```
public class First {

    public int var = 1; 

    public static void main(String args[]){

    Second Second = new Second();

    System.out.println(var);

    Second.test(); 

    System.out.println(var);

}
}

public class Second {

    void test(){
    /*
     * 
     * I try to change var to 2, and it works in this class
     * but when it doesn't change in the class "First"
     * 
     */
    First.var = 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you've changed it in second class, but you did not return it back to the first class. First class can't possibly know you've changed it in the other class if you don't return it.
You can do it this way, hope it helps.

First class:

```
public class First {

    public static void main(String args[]){


        int var = 1;

        Second Second = new Second();

        System.out.println(var); //Prints out 1

        var = Second.test(var); 

        System.out.println(var); //Prints out 2

    }
}
```

Second class:

```
public class Second {

    int test(int var){

        var = 2;

        System.out.println(var); //Prints out 2

        return var;

    }
}
```