# How to change the value of a variable set to null from another class?

Tags: java

I am having problems to change the value of a variable. I found [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668759/how-do-i-change-a-variable-from-a-different-class-in-java) older question, but I am still having problems to apply it to my code. If someone can review my code and give some guidance I will really appreciate it. This is my code:

```
public class GMTime {

    private static String time;
    private static int hour;
    private static int minutes;
    private static int colon;
    private static String error = null;

    // **********************************************************
    // constructor passing time as a string
    public GMTime(String temp) {
        time = temp;
    }
    // end constructor
    // **********************************************************
    // method checking the colon presence and place between 1-2 index

    public String colonCheck(String error) {
        while (time.contains(":")) {
            colon = time.indexOf(":");
        } // end of while
        if (colon != 1 || colon != 2) {
            error = "Invalid separator entered";
        }
        System.out.println(error);
        return error;
    } // end colon check
    public static String getError(){
    return error;
    }
}
```

Driver:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GMUnit6Ch15{

    public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String time;
    System.out.print("Enter time in the form mm:dd (\"q\" to quit) :");
    time = stdIn.next();

    while (!time.equalsIgnoreCase("q")){

    GMTime userTime = new GMTime(time);

    System.out.print("Enter time in the form mm:dd (\"q\" to quit) :");
    time = stdIn.next();

    }
```

I added this just to test if the modified error works.

```
    System.out.println(GMTime.getError()); 


    }//end of main
```

}// end of class

What I want to do is if "colon" is not present in "time" change the value of "error" so that I can print it later from the driver.

Comment: Could you also post the driver class (as well as exemplar input / output), so we can take a look to the whole program?

Comment: Definitely, Is a work in progress though.

Comment: Where are you invoking colonCheck()?  What is the expected result?

Comment: I am trying to change error in colonCheck() and then later invoque it getError. I know imy code is very poor I am sorry if I dont explain myself better, I am a beginner at java.

Comment: I don't see how the title fits the actual problem description here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least three problems in GMTime and colonCheck():

1. The variables in `GMTime` seems not required to be `static`.
2. The `while (time.contains(":"))` loop may be an infinite loop.
3. The statement `if (colon != 1 || colon != 2)` is actually always true, no matter what value `colon` is.

One plausible way to fix these issues is as below (I have tested the code, so please try to start from here and complete the whole program):

GMTime class:

```
public class GMTime {

    private String time;
    private int hour;
    private int minutes;
    private int colon;
    private String error = null;

    // **********************************************************
    // constructor passing time as a string
    public GMTime(String temp) {
        time = temp;
    }
    // end constructor
    // **********************************************************
    // method checking the colon presence and place between 1-2 index

    public void colonCheck() {
        while (time.contains(":")) {
            colon = time.indexOf(":");
            time = time.substring(colon + 1);
        } // end of while
        if (colon != 1 && colon != 2) {
            error = "Invalid separator entered";
        } else {
            error = "No error";
        }
    } // end colon check

    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }
}
```

GMUnit6Ch15 class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GMUnit6Ch15 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String time;
        System.out.print("Enter time in the form mm:dd (\"q\" to quit) :");
        time = stdIn.next();

        while (!time.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {

            GMTime userTime = new GMTime(time);
            userTime.colonCheck();
            System.out.println(userTime.getError());

            System.out.print("Enter time in the form mm:dd (\"q\" to quit) :");
            time = stdIn.next();            
        }
    }
}
```

Exemplar input / output:

> Enter time in the form mm:dd ("q" to quit) :1111
>
> Invalid separator entered
>
> Enter time in the form mm:dd ("q" to quit) :11:11
>
> No error
>
> Enter time in the form mm:dd ("q" to quit) :q

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review my code I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Elrascabuches Thanks a lot :-)